# Android - Master/Detail flow with Media Player

Tags: android, audio-player, android-music-player

how develop this type of layout?

if song playing then it show otherwise not..

which should display over master/Detail.... as well update progress of playing song.

[image]

[image]

**i want it for Android 4.0 or above** for both portrait & landscape

Please Help me..

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you should use `FrameLayout`. You can declare `NavigationDrawer` with `ListView` as the first layout ([NavigationDrawer reference](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html)) and then a "steering" of music player layout with progressbar as the second. The progress bar can be achieved with a `SeekBar`.
You can show/hide the second layout programmatically with `setVisibility(int visibility)`

[Here](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-building-audio-player-tutorial/) you have a nice reference and tutorial.